# Can't access dashboard, no access to FTP

Tags: dashboard, fatal-error, ftp

A friend was renovating plugins and the WP website crashed. They have lost touch with the developers so they don't know where it's hosted... Any help would be much appreciated. The website is plainvienna.at

Comment: They'll have to get in touch with the developers, unfortunately. It appears that `WP_DEBUG` is turned on on that site; hopefully your friend is able to make use of the information displayed there.

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach is to retrieve emails related to the website setup. Reach out to someone who might have valuable insights on accessing either the wp-admin users or the hosting service provider account.

Look for any clues in email threads, chat history, or any other information that could lead you to the previous developers. If none of this would work, gaining access to the backend might be challenging without this additional information.